# Compare same time serie from two different sources

Tags: time-series

I'm looking for a method to check if a time series obtained from one source is equal to same time series stored in another source.

Let me explain the case:

I have a data logger that gets data from 5 sensors and uploads these data to a central system. Along the upload process, can occurs some problems that may origin differences between original series and stored ones.

So I would like to calculate some kind of statistical indicator (like a CRC in communications) that I can send along with time series and allows me to compare this indicator with the one calculated from time series stored.

Thanks for your help in advance!!

Comment: Do you assume these 5 series should be similar, and are looking for a way to statistically describe how similar they are? Or looking for a way to construct to most probable(real) time series out of these 5 series?

Comment: Thanks for your reply DaFanat, exact, these 5 series should be similar or close to similar to those stored in central system (maybe series stored in central system may miss some points). So I need a way to compare each serie with their analogous in central system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several algorithms/methods for measuring similarity between two time series.
A first possible step in deciding which one will work best is comparing the two time series meta features: Length, frequency, scale.
If I understand correctly, in your questions the two time series to be compared should have the same frequency and scale, and might differ a bit on the length(due to some missing points in the central system).
Given that this missing points rate is low and random, and that you can align the two time series(starting at the same point).
It makes sense using Euclidean distance or other 'standard' distance metrics.
You can look into the [Earth moving distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) too, this distance is less sensitive to one time differences.

If number of missing points is meaningful, or aligning time series is hard. You can try using [Dynamic time wrapping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping) - this algorithms takes into account the possibility that the two time series indices are not aligned/ their alignment changes through the series.

This [10 pages paper](https://www.iiia.csic.es/sites/default/files/4584.pdf) explains some of what I've suggested and introduces another method for comparing time series.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much DaFanat, these alternatives you proposed me looks very good for what I was looking for.